# Creating specialised dictionary file for VIM (from Wikipedia?)

Tags: vim, dictionary

I use VIM's dictionary completion feature very frequently, yet have found it unhelpful when it comes to 'specialized' terminology, in my case German philosophical terms. I would now like to create my own dictionary file filled with philosophical terms that I can feed VIM with.

How could one create such a file? I was thinking Wikipedia would be a good place to start? Or extracting all `<h3>` headers from [this site](http://www.philosophie-woerterbuch.de/stichwortverzeichnis/)?

Looking forward to any suggestions!

Comment: I found a first easy to use list [here](http://www.philolex.de/sachregi.htm) to get me started.

Comment: *Dasein* is missing!

Comment: P.S. See `:help dictionary` and http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Dictionary_completions -> If you get that working the way you want, you can add your own answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I've started a [GitHub project](https://github.com/montauk/phil-liste) for anyone interested.